# RegEx match header with multi-line value

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net

I have the email header below :

```
To: <email@domain.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?dGnDqnUgxJHhu4Ega2jDtG5nIHRp4bq/bmcgdmnhu4d0IGhvw6BuIHRv?=
    =?utf-8?B?w6Bu?=
Date: Sat, 7 Jun 2014 21:39:10 +0700
```

I using this regex query to match the subject header :

```
Subject: ([^\r\n]*\r\n  [^\r\n]*)
```

However some case the subject have more and more extra line:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?dGnDqnUgxJHhu4Ega2jDtG5nIHRp4bq/bmcgdmnhu4d0IGhvw6BuIHRv?=
    =?utf-8?B?w6Bu4Ega2jDtG5nIHRp4bq/bmcgdmnhu4d0IGhvw6BuIHRv?=
    =?utf-8?B?w6Bu4Ega2jDtG5nIHRp4bq/bmcgdmnhu4d0IGhvw6BuIHRv?=
```

Or just one line:

```
Subject: =?utf-8?B?dGnDqnUgxJHhu4Ega2jDtG5nIHRp4bq/bmcgdmnhu4d0IGhvw6BuIHRv?=
```

How can i edit the query to match all case ?

Answer (score 1):

That would be:

```
Subject: ((?:[^\r\n]*\r\n)+  [^\r\n]*)
```

[rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/WtpDm6TRHF)

Answer (score 0):

If **Subject** is always followed by **Date** you could try this as well:

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eD8uO6)

```
/Subject: .*(?=Date)/s
```

- **`/s`** will make it work with one or multiple lines.